# Casting long and ints just using bitwise

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I am trying to reproduce the output of the following function using only the bit-wise operators ! ~ & ^ | + << >>.

```
int test_dl2(int x, int y) { 
   long long lsum = (long long) x + y;
   return lsum == (int) lsum;
}
```

All of my testing shows that the answer to everything is just 1. However the auto-tester that tells you if a question is right says just returning one is not correct.

In what situations to this is the answer not 1?
And if the function is not replicated like so:

```
int test_dl2(int x, int y) { 
   return 1;
}
```

What would the correct function/expression be (Using only the said bitwise operators)?

Comment: Unless with integer promotion, you cannot change a variable type by just using operators.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre my question was a bit poorly worded (Will correct in a second) I am trying to reproduce the output of the function, not the contents.

Comment: It isn't quite clear what is allowed and what is not in your function.

Comment: @n.m. you are allowed to use the operators  ! ~ & ^ | + << >> (So not -, &&, ||, *, /, ==, loops, if statements, or any other operators), you can use any numbers, and you can use variables. Does this help?

Comment: It is clear now, but it seems there is no correct solution to this, regardless of what you are allowed to use. `lsum == (int) lsum` either evaluates to 1 or has undefined behaviour.

Comment: `lsum == (int) lsum` is not UB.  Rather "result is
implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are trying to check if the addition of *x* and *y* will give a valid result as an uint32_t. The problem, as already stated in the comments, is that if the number is too "large", conversion from uint64_t to uint32_t is undefined.

Presently neither C nor C++ assume that numbers are represented as two's complement and making this kind of verification is difficult. This is going to change as the next C++ standard will enforce the use of [two's complement to code signed integers](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2218.htm) (and presumably the C standard will follow).

But this will not give a meaning to an incorrect conversion and your code will still be invalid.

Some tests can be done, if we assume that the numbers are coded in two's complement (and this is already the behavior in most computers).

Several solutions can be used. Here is one that mostly relies on bitwise operators.

Outline of the method is:

- left shift numbers to divide them by two (assumes left shifts on signed are arithmetic, which is true on most computers, but not required presently by the standard)
- add them. This will compute *x/2+y/2* and it will be equal to *(x+y)/2* **except** if both LSB of *x* and *y* are ones, in which case there is a carry generated at weight 2^1 in *x+y*.
  We test the existence of this carry by *and*ing the LSB of *x* and *y* and we add it to the sum.
- the result of the previous computation *(x+y)/2* is always valid on 32 bits. We check if it is valid on 31 bits. If it is true, *x+y* will be valid on 32 bits.
  Checking for this validity is simply done by comparing bits 31 and 30. If they are equal, the result can be converted on 31 bits safely. Otherwise, conversion will induce a sign change.

```
int is_add32_valid(uint32_t x, uint32_t y) { 
  uint32_t z = (x>>1) + (y>>1) + (x & y & 0x1) ;
  return !( (z ^ (z <<1)) & (1 << 31) ) ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following test returns `0` for your function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int test_dl2(int x, int y) { 
   long long lsum = (long long) x + y;
   return lsum == (int) lsum;
}

int main() {
    printf("%d", test_dl2(INT_MAX, 1));
    return 0;
}
```

The number that I used is the maximum of `int` which causes overflow. Your code is for testing overflow in `int`, so you need to test it with values that causes overflow in `+` for `int`. There are a lot of tests to show this overflow and mine is just an example.

**Update:**

As mentioned in comments, `lsum == (int) lsum` part in your code in implementation-defined in `C`, so you cannot relay in function results at all. My argument is correct if data types were unsigned (`unsigned int` and `unsigned long long`). This code is also implementation defined till `C++20` in `C++`. After `C++20`, it is defined in `C++` again.

Comment: The function has undefined behaviour for these inputs. It may return 0, it may return 1, it may set your computer on fire.

Comment: @n.m. why undefined behavior? I cannot see it. value of `x` should be convertible to `long long` and after becoming `long long`, `+` will not be undefined anymore because it is less than `LLONG_MAX`. is undefined behavior in downcasting from `long long` to `int` again?

Comment: @n.m. updated answer to include implementation defined for both `c` and `c++`.

Comment: Yes, long.long is converted back to int at which point it overflows. Integer overflow is UB.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. "long.long is converted back to int at which point it overflows" is not `int` overflow and **not UB**.  Instead "Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised."

Comment: @chux ah alrighty, it's implementation-defined, not UB. Not that different in practice but hopefully your implementation doesn't define this as "set computer on fire".

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica as I updated my reply, I wrote that this code is implementation defined. but if numbers were unsigned, you could use this code to detect overflow in addition of `unsigned int`.

Answer (score 0):

It should return 0 if x + y is greater then tmax or smaller then tmin.

Otherwise it will return 1.